# js querySelectorAll() that contains specific string in className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm rendering custom component in `app.js`

```
return (
    {cards.map((index) => {
        return <Card key={index} />
)
```

In `Card` I put specific `className`

```
return (
    <ListItem id="root" className="find-card"> ...
```

Since `<ListItem/>` itself is a part of `material-ui`, so it transforms `className` into

```
<li class="MuiListItem-root find-card MuiListItem-gutters" id="root">
```

How then to use `querySelectorAll()` so it could find all items that contain specific string within `className`?

I've tried using same approach as in [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)  `document.querySelectorAll('li[find-card]')` but it is not found.

### edit1:

I've followed your advices and browser console `document.querySelectorAll(".find-card")` logs all of my items.

I'm trying to implement `lazy load` and here is the `hook`

```
const imagesRef = useRef(null)

useEffect(
    () => {
        imagesRef.current = document.querySelectorAll(".find-card")
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".find-card"))            
    },
    [imagesRef, cardData.cards]
)
```

on start amount of cards is `0`, but on scroll amount changes, that hook triggers but logs `NodeList []`. I have another hook that logs amount of data loaded before that `lazy load` thing. In other words when items are loaded that thing still shows `0`, but browser console shows correct amount. Basically problem must be in hook

### edit2:

I've updated abovemetioned `useEffect`

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        imagesRef.current = document.querySelectorAll(".find-card")         
        console.log(cardData.cards)
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".find-card"))

        ...
```

That is what I have in log. At first array is empty, then it is filled, yet hook cant find anything.

```
[]
NodeList []

(5) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
NodeList []
```

### solution:

To recap comment section

`setTimeout()` was required and `document.querySelectorAll(".find-card")` works well.

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            imagesRef.current = document.querySelectorAll(".find-card")
            console.log(cardData.players)
        }, 10)
    },
    [cardData.cards]
)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `.find-card`?

Comment: not directly answering your question, but being that you are using React, do you really have to use DOM references?  Have you tried to see if there is a way you can use useRef or extract it using Props or State first?  It seems like a really bad idea to be hooking directly into Material-UI element's classes to get DOM references to manage your list, rather than acting on your source data

Comment: @BenM it returns `NodeList []`

Comment: @user120242 if I'm adding `className` to `<div/>` then it logs properly. Probably thats not about `react`

Comment: no ya, I know.  I'm just making a commentary that when using React, something like this really should be a last resort.  Especially when it comes to prepackaged UI components that already expose refs.  It's fully possible you have a good reason to have to do it though.  Just pointing out it really is something to use as a last resort, and it's very, very rare that there is a good reason to do it, and dealing with the complexity of hooking component lifecycles and dirty data checking to make sure your DOM hooks are being done right

Comment: @user120242 thanks! I'm just newbie and trying to make my own `lazy load` hook using guides. Basically that is working with default components but `material-ui` made it complicated.

Comment: `li[find-card]` think about that,since `[]` is an **attribute selector**, that's just like saying "Go find `<li find-card=""`>" elements. `find-card` is not a valid HTML5 attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't know you're looking for a class name. You have to denote it as `.find-card` so querySelectorAll knows to look for that class. That should be it to grab all the elements that have that class name, shouldn't be more complicated than that I don't think.

`document.querySelectorAll('.find-card')`

Comment: Unfortunately using that it returns `NodeList []`

Comment: Something else must be going on then, I would need a codepen that reproduces the issue. Right now if you open your inspector on this webpage right here and in the console typed: `document.querySelectorAll(".prettyprint");` you get results back so that is correct syntax. Could it be that you have an `id="root"` on multiple cards? There can only be 1 unique id on the page at all times.

Comment: Using console I get all my items from `document.querySelectorAll(".find-card")`. I'll add more info about it to the post

Comment: Maybe you're calling `document.querySelectorAll` too soon? Has the page rendered by the time you've called your method? If it's called too soon that would explain the lack of elements in the list

Comment: I've updated the post.  `document.querySelectorAll()` occurs only after items were added according to log. But I assume that logger is also showing me incorrect data. I need to check the rest.

Comment: Made another update with log of other data. In fact everything updates well. There must be another reason

Comment: I don't see a good reason as to why it would come back with no data unless the data just simply isn't ready at that point. For testing sake, maybe put a timeout around the console.log and see if it waits 2 seconds if there's any data? I would also look into using an elementRef on the list container and accessing the elements through that parent element ref. I'm just not seeing why that wouldn't work but honestly I think best practice would be to use an elementRef instead.

Comment: Yes! Also thought of timeout and you know, it worked, thank you.

Comment: I'm happy that worked but just for future reference that's not good practice lol you want everything to be activated when it's precisely needed to, timeout's are definitely not the way to do that. If an element ref isn't working for you, I would look into maybe a state variable like `pageReady` or `shouldLoadData` that you can check in the `useEffect` or `componentDidUpdate` and then once that's true, attempt to retrieve the elements.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that useEffect is in the wrong component, so it isn't actually hooking the ListItem component mounting.

Answer (score 1):

To get elements with the 'find-card' class, use this code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class="find-card"], [class^="find-card "], [class$=" find-card"], [class*=" find-card "]');
```

You can also use

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.find-card');
```

or

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('find-card');
```

**EDIT:**

This works too:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class~="find-card"]');
```

Comment: I don't really know why but searching with full name also does not work not the other string. Still having `NodeList []`  . edit. new option does not work either

Comment: You can use `document.getElementsByClassName("find-card")` as well.

Comment: @user120242 yeah, I'm using inspectior. And yes mui has some kind of generator with I can't turn off. Could find that.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('find-card');` returns `HTMLCollection []`

Comment: @JayJayAbrams right, the components are already wrapped and componentized in such a way that those things shouldn't be exposed.  Generally this kind of thing would be discouraged as an antipattern.  Anyhow, get rid of the `li` in front.  ListItems don't use li

Comment: I removed the `li` in front of the attribute selectors.